# Texto não inserindo quebra de linha

Tags: php, html, mysql, editor-de-texto, quebras-de-linha

Dei uma pesquisada e não encontrei nenhum post sobre o problema que estou enfrentando.

Estou fazendo uma busca no banco de dados e escrevendo na tela o que encontro. Porém quando o texto é exibido ele não está inserindo quebra de linha, com isso o texto fica tudo em uma linha.

Abaixo coloco as imagens do problema e de como é feita a implementação (Um Trecho).

```
<div class="row">  
  <div class="col-12 mb-3 text-center">
     <?php echo $results['descricao']; ?>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A não ser que o texto no banco esteja já marcado com HTML, você terá essa "tripa" na tela. Se você procura apresentar o texto na sua disposição original de espaçamento e linhas, ainda que não esteja marcado com HTML, envolva-o com a [tag pre](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/pre).

É bastante comum processar o texto do banco antes de exibi-lo. Por exemplo, pode carregar o texto num vetor, dividido em parágrafos. Depois imprima cada elemento desse vetor (um parágrafo) com o [elemento HTML parágrafo](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/p):

```php
$paragrafos = explode("\n\n", $texto);
foreach($paragrafos as $paragrafo) {
  echo '<p>' . $paragrafo . '</p>';
}
```

Dê uma olhadinha em [explode](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.explode.php) e [foreach](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/control-structures.foreach.php).